# Kerberos password-less ticket authentication

Tags: bash, security, authentication, kerberos

I'm trying to implement "password-less" Kerberos authentication (except when the ticket is expired) for a particular simple service within an organisation. (Full disclosure: It's not a web service, but "remote procedure execution" over SSH.) I'd prefer to just use Bash or perhaps Python for this.

Let's say a user passes their Kerberos credentials cache file, which by default is created at `/tmp/krb5cc_$(id -u)` at login to the client computer, through a client script to my service which sits on a different computer/server.

Is there some way I can determine whether this user is in fact who they claim to be, i.e. authenticate them against our Kerberos/AD? I can run this:

```
klist -s ${cache_file}
```

... and capture the return code in `$?` (0 means the cache file is readable and not expired), but is `klist` really a sufficient test for authenticity? E.g. if a malicious user sets up their own Kerberos server, could they successfully use a Kerberos ticket from this server instead?

Comment: If your Linux users get a Kerberos TGT at login time _(from SSSD I guess)_ and that TGT gets automagically renewed/recreated _(ditto)_ then the proper way to setup SSO (Single Sign-On) would be to enable SPNego auth in your web service. Client tries to connect, server returns a 401 challenge, client gets a service ticket for `HTTP/host.fqdn@DOMAIN` based on their TGT, client retries to connect with a hash of the ticket in a header, server is happy.

Comment: There is no way Kerberos can be associated with "simple". If you want something simple and unsecure, be creative. If you want something simple and (somewhat) secure, require your client to `bcrypt` a passphrase with some randomly-defined-by-server salt or sthg like that. If you want serious security, use a crypto protocol end-to-end _(SSL mutual auth, Kerberos, etc)_

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter - thanks for your comments! I forgot to explain that my "service" isn't actually a web service - it's "remote procedure execution" over SSH. Also, when a user logs in on a client host, `klist` shows 3 different tickets: If I understand correctly there are two TGTs and one other one to do with the client host.

Comment: SSH supports Kerberos auth (via GSSAPI library) out of the box => the RPC service can trust the `uid` of the local process spawned by the client when connecting to the service => problem solved...

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter Yes, but the RPC service is run with a shared user, so it doesn't tell me who actually initiated the call. Anyway, I think I have devised a "creative" solution like you suggested above, maybe something like: 1) Client asks to run the procedure. 2) Server looks for a certain random file in a shared area, doesn't find it, replies to client "I want $file!". 3) Client creates $file, asks again to run the procedure. 4) Server now finds $file, reads who owns $file and uses that as proof of the identity of the client/user. Problem solved!?

Comment: Sounds like a reasonable workaround -- start a "Pentest Bug Bounty" to make sure it's good enough ;-)